# Comma in "more than $6 billion to settle a long-running lawsuit, in a pact that also permits"

Tags: punctuation, commas, clauses

> Visa Inc.,  MasterCard Inc. and some large banks agreed to pay scores of retailers—from giant Publix Supermarkets Inc. to an interior-design store in Minnesota—more than $6 billion to settle **a long-running lawsuit, in a pact** that also permits merchants to charge more to customers who pay with credit cards. — [WSJ](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052702303919504577525284273006706.html?mod=googlenews_wsj)

How would the meaning change if that comma between "lawsuit" and "in a pact" is removed?

Another example:

> - The two sides have agreed to stop fighting in a pact that allows further peace talks.
> - The two sides have agreed to **stop fighting, in a pact** that allows further peace talks.

Comment: Also see [Charge more to customers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74538), a Nortonn S question

Answer (score 4):

It would not change the meaning at all in this case. Removing the comma could conceivably shift the referent of "in a pact" from "agreed" to "lawsuit", except that it makes no sense to consider a lawsuit as part of a pact, at least in this context.

Edit to answer OP's comment question: 
Example where the meaning could arguably change:

- The kids agreed to stop fighting after dinner. *They have been fighting after dinner...but now they have agreed to stop.*
- The kids agreed to stop fighting, after dinner. *They fought at any time, and it was not until after dinner that they agreed to stop.*

Comment: I added another example in my original post.  So, these are the same?

Comment: Arguably clues as to the linguistic competence of the writer are part of the meaning (or, at least, *"meta-meaning"*). In such a convoluted sentence as OP's example, I think any competent writer would include the comma, so the lack of it would tell me the writer wasn't actually very good at his job.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, JeffSahol!  For the kids fighting example, I see they both could mean that 1) the agreement took place after dinner, or 2) the agreement was for a post-dinner stoppage of the fighting.  Which sentence should have which meaning?

Comment: Both of your examples could mean that the kids agreed that they would continue to fight until they had had dinner, when they would stop.

Comment: Agreed, @AndrewLeach. There is no perfect example (one that is unambiguously defined by the presence or absence of the comma), ... I was just trying to help the OP with his questions.

Answer (score 1):

It would change the meaning entirely in this case. Removing the comma would conceivably shift the referent of "in a pact" from "agreed" to "lawsuit", except that it makes no sense to consider a lawsuit as part of a pact, at least in this context.